# Hard time using EventListener on dynamically created element with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Hi all I am a software engineer working on cloud computing(Mostly scripting). I wanted to learn web development and started with some basic course and learnt HTML,CSS. But when i came to JavaScript in the beginning it was fine, but later when it came to dynamic elements i started getting difficulty in eventListner to those dynamically created element with plan JavaScript. whereas with jquery its way easy with function like on(). The thing is, while learning all these i came up with lots of articles and youtube videos about javascript have evolved a lot and jQuery not so much relevant in 2020. so my question is

1) As a beginner in web development Should i avoid jquery totally.

2) or jquery is still very much thriving and should i mix both and learn.

Comment: I think there is no strict answer to your points. I don't use jQuery, but it is my personal choice. From learning perspective I would suggest you to stick with vanilla javascript first and then check out jQuery.

Comment: Notice, that [Event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) contains also answers not using jQuery. Answers to questions #1 and #2 can only be opinion based, they're not good Q&A questions.